# How to fix AccessDenied issue on transloadit cropped image upload?

Tags: jquery, transloadit

I am using transloadit image upload librabry to upload image and to upload image I am using below jQuery code.

```
          $('#submit_form').transloadit({
                wait: true,
                triggerUploadOnFileSelection: false,
                autoSubmit:false,
                params: {
                    auth: {
                        key: "<key>"
                    },
                    steps: {
                        "cropped_thumb": {
                          "use": ":original",
                          "robot": "/image/resize",
                          "result": true,
                          "crop": {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2:50, y2:50},
                          "resize_strategy": "crop"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

For normal image upload there is not issue but for cropped image it gives `AccessDenied` error while accessing image from URL https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tmp-eu-west-1.transloadit.com/9b177f304a1011e78e79d5120ae495ad.jpg
[image]
Please help me to fix this issue. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transloadit only stores the files for 24 hours.  You are probably trying to access that file after 24 hours since the execution of your assembly. You could also export the robot to any kind of support storage provider through another step if you want to save the results forever on your side.

Comment: Transloadit only stores the files for 24 hours? Its not true because in my project all files are coming from transloadit. The issue is only for cropped image. I don't want to store image on my server.

Comment: I work at Transloadit, and we only store files for 24 hours before deleting them from our servers please make sure to store all your encoding results on your servers or export them somewhere.

Comment: I don't think so because you can check here on my site demostore.renterval.com. all product images are coming from transloadit and its not saved before 24 hours man :P :P

Comment: All other images that are on aws are on your specific bucket. Except one which is on Transloadit and it is giving access denied.

Comment: Please contact us at support@transloadit.com and we will make sure to investigate this for you.